# My nested ng-repeat isn't working

Tags: angularjs

Trying this:

```
<div ng-repeat="store in something111.company2.store">
    {{store.name}}
    <div ng-repeat="section in something111.company2.store.section">
        {{section.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Getting this:

```
DePere
Green Bay
```

This is my user.company2:

```
{
"_id":"5473fc8c14034efd3c2b3d58",
"name":"Festival",
"__v":0,
"store":[{
  "_id":"5473fc8c14034efd3c2b3d59",
  "name":"DePere",
  "__v":0,
   "section":
     [{
    "_id":"5478b54c945d4c00001aa5f9",
     "name":"Deli",
   "__v":0}]},
    {
   "_id":"54747f498e16571b6049e266",
   "name":"Green Bay",
   "__v":0,
   "section":
     [{
     "_id":"547930057f7aa70000ee568f",
     "name":"Produce",
     "__v":0}]}]}
```

Produce should be showing up under Green Bay and Deli should be showing up under DePere, but they're not. company2.store works but company2.store.section doesn't... or something's wrong with the ng-repeat.

What should I do to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For inner `ng-repeat`, begin the 'path' at the point where you finish the outer one:

```
<div ng-repeat="store in something111.company2.store">
  {{store.name}}
  <div ng-repeat="section in store.section">
    {{section.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

In this case, inner `ng-repeat` will iterate over the collection stored in `section` property of *every* element of array stored in `user.company2.store`. Currently, you're trying to access `user.company2.store.section` directly - and fail, because there's no such property as `section` in `user.company2.store` *array*.